# Change resolution of webrtc video stream in android

Tags: android, webrtc, resolution

I want to change the resolution of video stream in Webrtc android (org.webrtc) but I did not find any functions to do that.

As far as I know in javascript we have applyConstraints to change the MediaStreamTrack resolution. I tried to find in android org.webrtc library MediaStreamTrack.class, there is no similar functions.

Please tell me how can I change the resolution of video stream from android side. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Video resolution can be changed from `VideoSource` ([link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/master/examples/androidapp/src/org/appspot/apprtc/PeerConnectionClient.java)):

```
videoSource.adaptOutputFormat(width, height, framerate);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done from `VideoCapturer`.

```
videoCapturer.changeCaptureFormat(updatedWidth, updatedHeight, VIDEO_FRAME_RATE);
```

works fine for me.